# How to import existing membership records

Tags: civimember, import

I am trying to import some old and existing membership but fail, which only the start date on 2015 can be imported.

In my xls, the other membership records on 01/01/2008, 01/06/1991...etc are all failed.

Any suggestion to import old existing membership records? or any configuration is missing?

Pleas help. Thanks.

Information as below,

Membership type : Associate /
-Duration  : 1 year /
-Period Type : rolling

Membership Status Rules : Complete /
-Start Event : Start date /
-End Event : End date

Comment: or any method to import the start date and end date which ignore the civicrm membership calculate? In this case, i'm just use membership for record but not require any renewal or payment function.

Comment: Update that set member since early than start date, and set more duration of member type, start date can be imported whatever 2015 or not, but the end date still confuse me that must set as 2015 or later year. Please help

Comment: I just tried importing memberships with dates in the past and had no problem.  What columns are you importing?  I just imported join, start, end and membership type.